# Аргументы конструктора SystemCpuUsage

Tags: c#, uwp

Всем доброго времени суток, появилась такая проблема, что я хочу получить данные о процессоре, но не могу, т.к. выдает ошибку:

> SystemCpuUsage не содержит конструктор, который принимает аргументы 0

Вот функция, которая получает и возвращает строку о процессоре:

```
public static string get_some()
    {
        SystemCpuUsage CPU = new SystemCpuUsage();
        return CPU.GetReport().ToString();
    }
```

Я перерыл всю документацию, но ничего толком не нашел, поэтому прошу вашей помощи.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Самая лучшая документация - сама студия. Она вам и подсказки и удобный инструментарий для просмотра всех доступных классов с их аргументами для вызова...

Answer (score 0):

Для получения отчета о процессоре для вашего собственного процесса перепишите код вот так

```
ProcessDiagnosticInfo process = ProcessDiagnosticInfo.GetForCurrentProcess();
ProcessCpuUsageReport report = process.CpuUsage.GetReport();
```

А для мониторинга других процессов читайте [UWP App Diagnostics](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/06/28/uwp-app-diagnostics/)